# How to get div so it always reaches the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I keep having this trouble whenever I code.

I set the height to 100%. I want the div to reach the bottom of the page no matter how much information is in it with the exception of a 300px margin at the bottom.

Currently I have not set the margin at the bottom yet.

As you can see, it does not reach the bottom of the page and I want it too. I realize your computer it may, since my screen is fairly big.

The DIV is called "wrapper".

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>Design At Ease - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<div id="logo"><a class="logoclass">DesignAtEase.com</a></div>
<ul id="headerlinks">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="coding.html">Coding</a></li>
<li><a href="graphics.html">Graphics</a></li>
<li><a href="database.html">Database</a></li>
<li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
<li><a href="more.html">More</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<ul id="quicklinks">
<li><a href="quickstart.html">Quick Start</a></li>
<li><a href="tagsmain.html">Tag Helper</a></li>
<li><a href="html.html">HTML</a></li>
<li><a href="css.html">CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="photoshop.html">Photoshop</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
background:#fffffc;
margin: auto auto;
}

#header{
background:#e5e5e5;
height:35px;
width:100%;
border-bottom: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
}

#headerlinks{
position:relative;
display:inline;
float:right;
margin-right:5%;
bottom:37px;
}

#headerlinks li{
display:inline;
padding-left:25px;
}

#headerlinks li a{
color:#777777;
display:inline;
font-size:18px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}

#headerlinks li a:hover{
color:#a3a3a3;
display:inline;
font-size:18px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}


#headerlinks li a:active{
color:#00B2EE;
display:inline;
font-size:18px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}


#logo{
position:relative;
color:black;
margin-left:5%;
top:5px;
}

.logoclass{
color:#212121;
display:inline;
font-size:24px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}

#quicklinks{
width:90%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;;
height:25px;
background:#e5e5e5;
border-bottom: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-left: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-right: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
top:-46px;
position:relative;
clear: right;
}

#quicklinks li{
position:relative;
top:2px;
display:inline;
padding-right:20px;
}

#quicklinks li a{
color:#777777;
display:inline;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}

#quicklinks li a:hover{
color:#a3a3a3;
display:inline;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}

#quicklinks li a:active{
color:#00B2EE;
display:inline;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}


#wrapper{
position:relative;
top:-62px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width:90%;
height:100%;
background:#fafafa;
border-left: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-right: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I always use.
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

You set:

```
 html, body {height: 100%;}
```

Add your 300px bottom padding to main wrapper and then negative margin -300px to footer to overlay it above that padding.

Use a huge wrapper for everything except the footer:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="main">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

Check out that link for more.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Using height 100% will take up 100% height of the container - so you'd need to set body and html to 100% height too.

Comment: I did so and it is still the same as it was.

Comment: Set * { height: 100%; } then set #MyDiv { height: 100%; background: #333; } This should work fine.

Comment: which div do I need to set to that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you wanna stick the `#wrapper` at bottom of the page (except some space from bottom)

I've changed your code in the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/FgGn5/**

```
#wrapper{
position:absolute;
bottom:20px;
margin: 0 5%;
width:90%;
height:20px;
background:red;
border-left: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-right: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
}
```

It needs an `absolute` position to stick to the bottom. Because of the `absolute` position, we are forced to specify `margin-right` and `margin-left`. Fortunately because of the percent base `width`, it's simple.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you'll have the best success across the various common browsers by employing a JavaScript solution. I would strongly suggest using jQuery to make your life a little easier. Then you could essentially set the #wrapper DIV equal to the body height minus the #header and #quicklinks. It would look something like this:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var headerHeight = $('#header').outerHeight(false);
var linksHeight = $('#quicklinks').outerHeight(false);
var wrapperHeight = windowHeight - (headerHeight + linksHeight);

$('#wrapper').css('min-height', wrapperHeight);
```

Note: I'm making using of min-height, because the contents of the #wrapper DIV may actually already push it to the bottom of the screen.

See this fiddle for a quick and dirty example: http://jsfiddle.net/HLJJc/